# Using Stringbuilder to set a filter for a datasource

Tags: vb.net, string, datasource, stringbuilder

If I set the filter writing the filter directly like

```
myBindingSource.Filter = "Team = 'TheAvangers'"
```

it works fine.

But I want to set the string with stringbuilder like

```
Dim sB as New StringBuilder
sb.append("""Team = 'TheAvangers'""")
myBindingSource.Filter = sb.toString
```

Unfortunately this doesnt work. No filter is set doing it this way.
I thought it could have something to do with the stringbuilder so I tried

```
dim strTest as string = """Team = 'TheAvangers'"""
myBindingSource.Filter = strTest
```

But this doesnt work too. Could anyone help me so I can use a String placeholder (I would prefer a STringbuilder solution)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not double the quotes. Just write

```
Dim sb as New StringBuilder
sb.Append("Team = 'TheAvangers'")
myBindingSource.Filter = sb.ToString
```